# Trigger a click button event from another button, using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I have an iframe in asp.net, using c# .
When the iframe with a story ends, I want to fire a button in parrent window via java script.

The iframe window has its own html file and js file. when the iframe come to an end of story
in the js file run

```
    case "ClosePlayer":    
    trig();    
    break;
```

then I call another js file with a simple function

```
    function trig()
   {    
    //$('#<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>').click();
    //document.getElementById('<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>').click();
    document.getElementById("SubmitButton").click();
   // alert("javascript here");

    }
```

in the main window in asp.net I have this button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProceedToNextTab" runat="server" Text="Proceed" OnClick="btnProceedToNextTab_Click"  />
```

and I want to trigger this with another button via javascript, so the code behind of the function `btnProceedToNextTab_Click();` run

`<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="trig();" />`

Can anyone help me? I tried to use jquery, but nothing fires the button. The alert messages show ok, but the button is never clicked.

Comment: i also have use from child window : parent.document.getElementById("SubmitButton").click();

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your parent window:

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#ButtonInIframeWindow").live('click',function(){


$('#submitButtonInParentWindow').click();


});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is false:

```
document.getElementById("SubmitButton").click();
```

you have to use jQuery selector like this:

```
$("#SubmitButon").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this...

You can invoke your click function in javascript function..

```
document.getElementById('btnProceedToNextTab').click();
```

Please feel free to mark as answer if it satisfies....

Answer (score 0):

ok found it.

from child (iframe window) call a js file with trig();

```
function trig()
```

{

```
var proceedButton = parent.$('[id$="btnProceedToNextTab"]');
proceedButton.trigger('click');
return false;
```

}

and in parent window:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProceedToNextTab" runat="server" Text="Proceed" Style="display:none;" OnClick="btnProceedToNextTab_Click"  />
```

works for me! thanks.